# Validate values in form arrays

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've a post value `members` and members is an array of values. How can I validate that one specific value is not in the list?

## Example

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'member_ids' => 'required|min:1|not_in:4',
]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: well, i guess, checking if some value exists in an array is not the matter of validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what it is you would like to achieve, but I think you can find a solution from here: http://laravel.io/forum/11-12-2014-how-to-validate-array-input

Answer (score 4):

Laravel 5.2 has [array validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays).

So try this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'member_ids.*' => 'required|not_in:4',
]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use another request-param? `'required|not_in:owner_id'`

Comment: @Gerrit you could use "different" rule, take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-different).
It should look like `required|different:owner_id`